# git: same commit checked out, file tracked, no local changes - but files have different contents

Tags: git

Same commit is checked out on two machines:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

(identical hash)

A file is being tracked on both machines:

```
git ls-files views/partials/about-content.hbs --error-unmatch; echo $?
```

Returns:

```
views/partials/about-content.hbs
0
```

There are no local differences:

```
git diff origin/master..HEAD
```

(no output on both machines)

When I open `views/partials/about-content.hbs` I can see completely different contents. Why?

Comment: `git diff origin/master HEAD` (you don't need `..`, here, because diffs are pairwise) only tells you about differences between two commits (`origin/master` and `HEAD`); it tells you nothing about *local changes*, i.e. differences between `HEAD` and the working tree. What do you get if you run `git diff HEAD -- views/partials/about-content.hbs`?

Comment: Does `git status` mention the file at any of the machines?